# Change File Permission at run time

Tags: chmod, chown

I have two users in a group.

```
Users:
   1) apache
   2) data
Group
   1) apache
```

I have three directories. The directory structure of that three directories are like below.

```
drwxrwx--- 10 data    apache 4096 Aug 21 14:30 Data
drwxrwx--- 10 data    apache 4096 Aug 21 14:30 App
drwxrwx--- 22 apache    apache 4096 Aug 22 12:04 www
```

I have a copy program in `App` directory. It will copy a file from `Data` directory to `www` directory. After the copy process over, the copied file are in the mode of below.

```
----r-----  1 apache apache   35003 Aug 22 11:47 wT89TQsATjE.txt
```

But I want to be that file permission as like below after the copy process.

```
-rw-rw----  1 apache apache   35003 Aug 22 11:47 wT89TQsATjE.txt
```

Could I change the mod of the file to be read as user and group after that copy process automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the permissions before the file is copied, you might copy them with `cp -a`, which will preserve permissions. This of course means, that your file has to have the permissions `-rw-rw----` set before copying.

As a second option, why not change the permissions of the file right after copying:

```
chmod 660 $copiedFile
```

Comment: I thought about it that second option. But the first answer you gave that I want. Thank you. I try to work with that.

Comment: @SmithDwayne do not forget to mark this answer as the solution.